# How to display the library name in Dart Editor?

Tags: dart

I think Dart Editor used to display the library name as a gray box next to the file name in the Files pane. For instance, if `foo.dart` started with

```
// foo.dart

library foo;
import  'dart:html';
```

the Files pane would show `foo.dart [foo]` and if I changed the library name to `bar` the display would change to `foo.dart [bar]`. Useful for debugging!

It does not seem to work in Editor 1.9.3, but that could be because some magic piece of info is cached and needs to be updated. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is something you need to update, I also didn't see it mentioned that this feature was removed. You could create a bug report at http://dartbug.com

Comment: I am using `Dart Editor version 1.10.0.dev_01_05 (DEV)` and the library name is shown.

Comment: Interesting. I upgraded the editor to 1.10 and still no library name displayed. It feels like time for a 100% reinstall of Dart. Does anyone on the Dart team have a comment?